# What is the value of the sum of the minimum in-degree and maximum out-degree of an Directed Acyclic Graph?

Tags: computer-science, graph-theory

What is the value of the sum of the minimum in-degree and maximum out-degree of an
Directed Acyclic Graph?

a) Depends on a Graph
b) Will always be zero
c) Will always be greater than zero
d) Maybe zero or greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

We can break this down into two parts: minimum in-degree and maximum out-degree.

The minimum in-degree of a DAG must be 0 which follows from the existence of a unique [topological ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for the graph.

The maximum out-degree of the graph may be zero, or any other positive number.

Two pathological DAG examples that illustrate the range of maximum out-degrees are:

1. a single node by itself (in-degree = out-degree = 0), so we know
   that this sum can be 0.
2. a star with one node connected to N-1 other nodes (minimum in-degree = 0, maximum out-degree = N-1)

So this suggests that a) or d) are correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer :**

```
d) Maybe zero or greater than zero.
```

**Theorem :**

```
Every finite DAG has at least one source, and at least one
sink. In fact, given any vertex v, there is a path from some
source to v, and a path from v to some sink.

Note: This theorem need not hold in an infinite DAG. For
example, this DAG has neither a source nor a sink.
```

**Explanation :**

```
There are three cases we can consider:

1. DAG with Single Node : Here both in-degree and out degree are zero. So sum of 
   minimum in-degree and maximum out-degree of an Directed Acyclic Graph is 0.  
 
2. Finite DAG : Since there is at least one sink for which out-degree is 0  and 
   a source whose in-degree is 0. But since we are considering maximum out- 
   degree then for any graph with more than one node out degree is greater or 
   equal to 1. Hence Sum of the minimum in-degree and maximum out-degree of an 
   DAG is greater equal to one.

3. Infinite DAG : Since theorem does not hold true for infinite DAG, so it can 
   even be without sink or source, so in any case  Sum of the minimum in-degree 
   and maximum out-degree of an DAG is greater than 0.

Considering all cases we see that sum is maybe 0 zero or greater than 0.
```